# Outlook add event when appointment start

Tags: c#, outlook, add-in

I am creating a outlook add in using C#. I want to add event to appointment so that when appointment occurs(start according to time), this event is fired.

```
    private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Outlook.MAPIFolder calendar = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar);
        Outlook.Items calendarItems = calendar.Items;
        Outlook.AppointmentItem item = calendarItems["Test"] as Outlook.AppointmentItem;
        item.SomeEvent += addSomeEvent;
    }
    void addSomeEvent(..........)
    {
        //custom implemantation
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

[**This**](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/162cef0e-c5f6-4648-b345-483911052ab4/outlook-calendar-events?forum=vsto) thread discusses how to do Calendar events.  You will likely need to create an appointment wrapper.  What that means is you will handle the event for Application.ItemLoad and create a "wrapper" if it's an appointment item.

Comment: ItemLoad didn't help. I want to show custom MessageBox for all appointments when the appointment occurs(according to start time).